# Convert Alphavantage API Response to DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, alpha-vantage

I have looked for other related topics on SO only finding similar issues, but nothing that can help me.

I am querying AlphaVantage for stock data. I recieved the data and decode, but am currently unable to convert to a pandas dataframe due to format issues. The response is in the below form:

```
{
    "Meta Data": {
        "1. Information": "Daily Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes",
        "2. Symbol": "AAPL",
        "3. Last Refreshed": "2021-04-26",
        "4. Output Size": "Full size",
        "5. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
    },
    "Time Series (Daily)": {
        "2021-04-26": {
            "1. open": "134.8300",
            "2. high": "135.0600",
            "3. low": "133.5600",
            "4. close": "134.7200",
            "5. volume": "66905069"
        },
        "2021-04-23": {
            "1. open": "132.1600",
            "2. high": "135.1200",
            "3. low": "132.1600",
            "4. close": "134.3200",
            "5. volume": "78756779"
        },
        "2021-04-22": {
            "1. open": "133.0400",
            "2. high": "134.1500",
            "3. low": "131.4100",
            "4. close": "131.9400",
            "5. volume": "84566456"
        },
```

After running the below code:

```py
import requests as rq
import json

base_url = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?"
params = {"function":function, "symbol":symbol, "outputsize":output_size, "datatype":data_type, "apikey":api_key}

response = rq.get(base_url, params=params)
data_str = data_bytes.decode("utf-8")
```

My issue arises when trying to load the data to a dataframe:

```py
data_dict = json.loads(data_str)
df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict.items())
df.head()
```

Returns:

```
    0   1
0   Meta Data   {'1. Information': 'Daily Prices (open, high, ...
1   Time Series (Daily)     {'2021-04-26': {'1. open': '134.8300', '2. hig...
```

And...

```py
data_dict = json.loads(data_str)
df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)
df.head()
```

Returns:

```
    Meta Data   Time Series (Daily)
1. Information  Daily Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes   NaN
2. Symbol   AAPL    NaN
3. Last Refreshed   2021-04-26  NaN
4. Output Size  Full size   NaN
5. Time Zone    US/Eastern  NaN
```

Which neither are usable. I am after a dataframe of the form:

```
date   open   high   low   close   volume
```

Is there a way to get the response into this format?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you need `Time Series (Daily)` values only. So you can use directly when you create dataframe

```
data_dict = json.loads(data_str)
df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict["Time Series (Daily)"])
df = df.T  # Transpose Dataframe for desired results
```